# Call tf.stop_gradient() on hidden states of recurrent neural network in Tensorflow/Keras

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras, backpropagation

I have a question on Tensorflow/Keras and the use of [tf.stop_gradient()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient) in connection to [RNN:s](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/working_with_rnns). In this pytorch [guide](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/main/word_language_model), they call [.detach()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.detach.html) on the hidden states that the model outputs before passing it to the model in the next iteration (see the 'Repackage hidden'-function on line 125 [here](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/main/word_language_model/main.py) and line 184 in the train-function [here](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/main/word_language_model/main.py)). I wonder if I can do the same in Tensorflow by calling tf.stop_gradient() on the hidden states that a RNN-layer/model outputs? (Or if there is another way to do this). If I understand it correctly, this would make it possible to pass hidden states to the next iteration, without them contributing to the backpropagation through time.